# aura:iteration doesn't rerender when changing attribute object[] under locker service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

Another issue that I found with locker service, I presume this is some kind of framework bug related to locker service (if someone can tell, I'd appreciate).

I have a simple component which has one attribute - `item`, which has one property `errors` that is array of objects. In the component I display errors using `aura:iteration`.

The problem happens when I will modify `item.errors` (in this example after calling `rerender` controller function.

In the `console.log` I can see the array has 3 elements (which is correct):
[image: Console.log result]

But on the screen I can see only one element being rendered:
[image: Screen result]

Component code:

```
<aura:component >

    <aura:attribute name="item" type="Object" access="global"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initialize}"/>

    <h1>This is sample component to show problem of aura:iteration and binding of attributes</h1>
    <a onclick="{!c.rerender}">RERENDER</a>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.item != null}">
        <span>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.item.errors}" var="err">
            <span>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!err.display}">
                    <div>{!err.message}</div>
                </aura:if>
            </span>
        </aura:iteration>
        </span>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

Controller Code:

```
({
    initialize : function(component, event, helper) {
        var item = {};

        var errs = [];
        var err1 = {};
        err1.display = true;
        err1.message = 'test error';

        errs.push(err1);
        item.errors = errs;
        component.set("v.item", item);
    },
    rerender : function(component, event, helper) {
        var item = component.get("v.item");

        item.errors = [];
        var err1 = {};
        err1.display = true;
        err1.message = 'test error';
        item.errors.push(err1);

        var err2 = {};
        err2.display = true;
        err2.message = 'test error 2';
        item.errors.push(err2);

        var err3 = {};
        err3.display = true;
        err3.message = 'test error 3';
        item.errors.push(err3);

        component.set("v.item", item);

        console.log(component.get("v.item"));
    }
})
```

**EDIT:** I suspect that it may come from the fact that newly added array elements were not wrapped into secure object (only 1st item was wrapped, 2nd and 3rd were not)?

[image: Array Elements]

**EDIT 2:** This doesn't happen when you iterate over an `object[]` attribute directly. In that case everything works as expected. The problem only happens when you iterate over a collection that is a property of some object:

This would work fine:

```
<aura:attribute name="errors" type="Object[]" access="global"/>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.errors}" var="err" indexVar="i">
    <span>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!err.display}">
            <div>{!err.message}</div>
        </aura:if>
    </span>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: It's not resolved for me. I'm seeing this issue in a production org. I have an iteration over a menuItem list, then look up some user information to determine whether to show or hide menu items, but the iteration never rerenders after the first time. I'm wondering if it's related to W-3458193 mentioned here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147740/locker-service-how-to-get-the-event-target/147745#147745 - the comment: > I believe the issue here is at the intersection of aura:iteration and Locker resulting in a sort of custody battle over ownership of the resulting DOM. Opened bug

Answer (score 2):

If you replace the first line of your `rerender` function with:

```
var item = {};
```

It successfully pushes all 3 errors to the view. So there are some problems with adding new members to the array inside the SecureObject, but if you push in a brand new object it's happy.

Note also that if you're sneaky enough to do:

```
component.set('v.item.errors', item.errors);
```

Then it appears to refresh the bindings to the array objects.

Comment: But wouldn't then item be a different instance of the object? That's not necessarily what I want to do. I'll try the second sneaky solution tomorrow. It would be also good to know if this is going to be fixed some day.

Comment: It would appear that the second sneaky solution does connect the updated data to the enclosing object. And yes the first line is not so much a solution as proof that the trouble lies in getting an object back out of the view and reusing it.

Comment: I've tried that and it seems to work. Do you have any workaround for situations where you have an object with array of objects, where one property is also an array? Naively I tried: component.set("v.item.components[0].componentDefinition", item.components[0].componentDefinition); but it didn't worked

Comment: No idea... the best I can come up with is to try having a private `aura:attribute`, let's say of type `Map`, and that it's called `fixer`... then try `component.set("v.fixer", item.components[0]); component.set("v.fixer.componentDefinition", item.components[0].componentDefinition);` ... and if necessary, then `component.set("v.item.components", item.components);` ... and hopefully it creates the needed bindings?

Comment: That sounds like an overkill, but thanks for suggestion. I spoke today with a sucess manager frm SFDC, he promised to get hold of some technical contact next week. I'll try to underline these two issue with bindings and uninitialized attributes, because current workarounds are a bit painful.

Comment: In case anybody would be looking at it - it seems the problem is resolved now.

Comment: @MaciekSimm What was the solution? I am also having the same issue. I want to delete a row from a table(which is iterating over object[]). Sample code be like:
var newArray=[];   var existingArr = component.get("v.data");  
iterate over a look and avoid the selected values(as I want to delete them), push the rest values;
component.set("v.data", newArray);

data is the attribute in the cmp file, which is of type object[].

Comment: @YsrShk - one of Summer 17' patches has fixed that issue I believe, at least when I tested it back in may. Since then I have abandoned LC because those Locker issues completely drained my faith in the framework. But I'm not sure your problem is similar. I think your problem is more about loosing reference. I would try to not create a new instance of the array (by declaring var newArray, and then calling component.set("v.data", newArray)) but instead I would try to mutate existing array, so: var existingArr = component.get("v.data"); existingArr.slice(...); component.set("v.data", existingArr)

Answer (score 1):

I am facing a similar issue when I update an Array Attribute which is being rendered inside of aura:iteration. When I add a property to the array's item value and set the attribute

> "component.set('v.arrAttr', arrAttr)"

the arrAttr doesnt get updated and isnt rerendered.
my work around is that I set arrAttr to null and then set to actual value in next line.

**Work Around**

> "component.set('v.arrAttr', null)"
>   "component.set('v.arrAttr', arrAttr)"

Comment: Also, if setting your `component.set('v.arrAttr', null)` triggers a re-render and your component throws an error because `arrAttr` is null. You could resolve that by adding it inside a try-catch-finally block to make sure `arrAttr` is set to correct value.


`try {
    component.set('v.arrAttr', null);
} catch(e) {
   // whatever
} finally {
    component.set('v.arrAttr', arrAttr);
}`