# Lockerservice and event.getSource()

Tags: lightning, locker-service, lightning-events

I have a few lightning components already written and those use `<lightning:x />` markup.

I am still not able to use `event.getSource()` instead of an `aura:id` in scenario where I do an `aura:iteration` and can not set a dynamic `aura:id`.

e.g.:

component.cmp

```
<aura:iteration items="{! v.items }" var="item">
  <lightning:input 
    type="checkbox" 
    onchange="{! c.onChange }" 
    name="{! item.name } 
    label="{! item.name }" 
  />
</aura:iteration>
```

Controller.js

```
onChange: function(component, event, helper) {
  const checkbox = event.getSource(); //getSource is not a function
}
```

Everywhere I can read answers saying that we should use `id` to create dynamic ids but with the lockerservice (14th June) we will not be able to use those kind of tricks (same as `event.target.value`).

Why this function does **never** work ?

Answer (score 3):

With locker services enabled, this will work from Spring 17, which I guess is already deployed to some editions.

Find the documentation [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_lightning_base_events.htm).

Similar question was answered [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144129/winter-17-release-event-getsource-is-not-a-function-on-lightningbutton).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is similar to the one reported here [Locker Service: How to get the event target?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147740/locker-service-how-to-get-the-event-target#147741)
We are working on a fix for this. W-3458193 is the work item with R&D, if you want to reference in your salesforce case.