# Anyone figure out how to get selected tab in lightning:tabset using onselect event

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Since `event.getSource()` always throws an error

> [event.getSource is not a function]

so the following is **impossible**:

[Code modified From Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_tabset.htm)

**Component**

```
<aura:component description="myProblemComponent" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <div aura:id="data-entry">
        <lightning:tabset onselect="{!c.tabSelected}" variant="default" selectedTabId="tab1">
            <lightning:tab tabindex="1" id="tab1" title="Tab 1" label="Tab 1">

                FIRST TAB
            </lightning:tab>
            <lightning:tab tabindex="2" id="tab2" title="Tab 2" label="Tab 2">
                Second tab
            </lightning:tab>
        </lightning:tabset>


    </div>


</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    tabSelected: function(component,event,helper){
        console.log('TAB SELECTED');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event));

        var a = event.target;

        console.log(a); //null

        var b = event.getSource(); //throws error [event.getSource is not a function]

        console.log(b);

    }
})
```

So how do we find out which tab has been selected from the `onselect` event?

**JSON.stringify(event.target)**  null

I also output the event as a JSON string if that helps...

**JSON.stringify(event)**

> {"srcElement":null,"isTrusted":false,"detail":{"selectedTab":{}},"NONE":0,"CAPTURING_PHASE":1,"AT_TARGET":2,"BUBBLING_PHASE":3,"MOUSEDOWN":1,"MOUSEUP":2,"MOUSEOVER":4,"MOUSEOUT":8,"MOUSEMOVE":16,"MOUSEDRAG":32,"CLICK":64,"DBLCLICK":128,"KEYDOWN":256,"KEYUP":512,"KEYPRESS":1024,"DRAGDROP":2048,"FOCUS":4096,"BLUR":8192,"SELECT":16384,"CHANGE":32768,"type":"onSelect","target":null,"currentTarget":null,"eventPhase":0,"bubbles":false,"cancelable":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"timeStamp":39604.285,"returnValue":true,"cancelBubble":false,"path":[],"composed":false}

I have tried to get it using `document.querySelector` but cannot seem to get the appropriate selector criteria... hmmmmm

I have tried this:

```
console.log(
     document.querySelector('li.slds-active')
);
```

but it always return null (**with locker service enabled**) despite the tab element looking like this:

```
<li class="slds-tabs--default__item slds-text-heading--label slds-active" role="presentation" title="Tab 1" data-aura-rendered-by="141:0">....</li>
```

when locker service is disabled it the querySelector works fine which I would expect but without another way to get the selected tab once locker service is force enabled there seems to be no way to tell which tab was selected... lightning:tabset

Just FYI, I attempted the solution to use onactive and this is what dev console shows (v38.0)

[image]

Comment: What version is your lightning components ? 38.0 or 39.0?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - I just made them 39.0 and disabled Locker service. Still did not work. I thought I saw a post earlier where getSource no longer worked with locker service but meh. I removed that tag. Maybe it is a `lightning` component beta thing. Will check using regular ui:tabset tonight....Still getting getSource is not a function

Comment: What does event.target.id output when you log it to the console?

Comment: I'll play with it more tonight. If I knew it worked with a given minimal example I could troubleshoot. But at this point I can not even get that to work so don't know if it is a bug or something I am doing wrong. Guess I am lacking direction lol

Comment: @sfdcfox - update question with full example as well as output....Also, while the meta for the lightning components appears to be 39 in my IDE, it must be at 38 as I am not able to set classes to 39 as it does not exist.

Comment: The sad thing is, end of 2018, docs haven't been updated yet with a working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

selectedTabId is actually a two-way binding. You can determine which tab is selected by setting it to an attribute. Here's your example, modified:

## .cmp

```
<aura:component description="myProblemComponent" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="selTabId" type="String" default="tab2" />
    <div aura:id="data-entry">
        <lightning:tabset onselect="{!c.tabSelected}" variant="default" selectedTabId="{!v.selTabId}">
            <lightning:tab aura:id="tab1" tabindex="1" id="tab1" title="Tab 1" label="Tab 1">

                FIRST TAB
            </lightning:tab>
            <lightning:tab aura:id="tab2" tabindex="2" id="tab2" title="Tab 2" label="Tab 2">
                Second tab
            </lightning:tab>
        </lightning:tabset>


    </div>
</aura:component>
```

## Controller.js

```
({
    tabSelected: function(component,event,helper) {
        alert(component.get("v.selTabId"));
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around....Much appreciated. Do you think the inability to use `getSource()` and `.get('v.id')` like in the documentation is a bug or something that will never be fixed due to locker service and namespacing or whatever the reason may be?

Comment: @Eric see [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155040). There's a bug with getSource that is apparently fixed in Spring 17. I feel that using an attribute is actually a better choice anyways, because it also allows you to programmatically specify the selected tab at runtime as well (imagine a button that takes you to a new tab).

Comment: If anyone else ends up here trying to do the same with LWC, this also works with LWC - just track the active-tab-value, and set it in your controller when you need to change it...

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented `<lightning:tabset>` in a different way - you should handle the onselect event on the `<lightning:tab>` markup, and set the body attribute for the tab content:

> Component

```
<lightning:tabset>

    <lightning:tab label="1st tab" onactive="{!c.loadFirstTab}" >

        <aura:set attribute="body">
            <lightning:card iconName="standard:report" title="first tab">
                This is my first tab
            </lightning:card>
        </aura:set>

    </lightning:tab>

    <lightning:tab onactive="{!c.loadSecondTab}">
        <aura:set attribute="label">
            Additional Report ( same as previous label attribute but here you can add also components)
        </aura:set>

        <aura:set attribute="body">
            <lightning:card iconName="standard:report" title="second tab">
                This is my second tab
            </lightning:card>
        </aura:set>

    </lightning:tab>

</lightning:tabset>
```

> Controller

```
({
    loadFirstTab : function(component, event, helper) {
        // do whatever you want
    },

    loadSecondTab : function(component, event, helper) {
        // do whatever you want
    }
})
```

The first tab is the default one so it loads the controller method when page loads. the second tab is loaded only upon clicking on it

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no event `onactive` for the lightning tab so it will not compile. I tried `onfocus` but it fired at unexpected times so it was not usable.....Appreciate the effort you put into the answer though.

Comment: But this really works for me - I did not invent it for the answer  ;o)

Comment: not sure how since it is not a documented attribute (v38/39) nor does the dev console allow you to save. See image in update question (v38). I believe you it works for you just cannot get it to save in my org....

Comment: did you put the onactive event on the <lightning:tab> component and not the <lightning:tabset>?

Comment: Yes, just like you have it in your code, on the `<lightning:tab>`. It also does not work on the `<lightning:tabset>` (fyi) - regardless, sfdcfox's answer seems more appropriate and less technical debt with not having to create a method for each tab

Comment: ok, no problems

Answer (score 0):

`event.getSource()` does not throw an error anymore.

`event.getSource().get("v.id")` works exactly as [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tabset/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleTabsLazy).

Comment: I almost thought getting the _selected tab/tabId_ via event was still an issue, because I did the following to find out what the event would tell me:

`JSON.stringify(event)` and `JSON.stringify(event.getSource())` - both return empty information as described by OP.

This led me to believe in a faulty behaviour but I was mistaken.