# Navigate to specific lightning:tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using lightning:tabset and lightning:tab tags in a lightning component. By default the first tab is displayed. If the user manually navigates to third tab and clicks a button which in third tab should bring the user back to first tab, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you add the code snippets to explain the issue ?

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158981